# Arrangement of products

Tags: flutter

Products are sorted to the right.
I want them to be sorted downwards.

The size of the widget is fine.
I asked for support from the support team. They said you have to do it yourself.
I am new to Flutter. I don't know what to do.
I did research on the internet. I searched ListView, GridView, scroll, Row, Column and many words and collected information from library. I just couldn't apply it.
Please help me.

Thanks

```
return Consumer<ProductProvider>(
      builder: (context, prodProvider, child) {
        List<Product> productList;
        if (productType == ProductType.LATEST_PRODUCT) {
          productList = prodProvider.latestProductList;
        }
        else if (productType == ProductType.POPULAR_PRODUCT) {
          productList = prodProvider.popularProductList;
        }
        if(productList == null ) {
          return productType == ProductType.POPULAR_PRODUCT ?
          SizedBox(
            height: 250,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
                  width: 195,
                  child: ProductWidgetWebShimmer(),
                );},
            ),
          ) :
          GridView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            gridDelegate:ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context) ? SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent( maxCrossAxisExtent: 195, mainAxisExtent: 250) :
            SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisSpacing: 5,
              mainAxisSpacing: 5,
              childAspectRatio: 4,
              crossAxisCount: ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context) ? 3 : ResponsiveHelper.isTab(context) ? 2 : 1,
            ),
            itemCount: 12,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context) ? ProductWidgetWebShimmer() : ProductShimmer(isEnabled: productList == null);
              },
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_SMALL),
          );
        }
        if(productList.length == 0) {
          return SizedBox();
        }

        return productType == ProductType.POPULAR_PRODUCT
            ? SizedBox(
              height: 250,
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: productList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
                    width: 195,
                    child: ProductWidgetWeb(product: productList[index], fromPopularItem: true),
                  );
                },
              ),
        ) :
        Column(children: [

          GridView.builder(
            gridDelegate: ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context)
                ? SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent( maxCrossAxisExtent: 195, mainAxisExtent: 250) :
            SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisSpacing: 5,
              mainAxisSpacing: 5,
              childAspectRatio: 3.5,
              crossAxisCount: ResponsiveHelper.isTab(context) ? 2 : 1,
            ),
            itemCount: productList.length,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_EXTRA_SMALL),
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context) ? Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: ProductWidgetWeb(product: productList[index]),
              ) : ProductWidget(product: productList[index]);
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 30),

          productList != null ? Padding(
            padding: ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context)? const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40,bottom: 70) :  const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            child: ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context) ?
            prodProvider.isLoading ? Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_SMALL),
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Theme.of(context).primaryColor)),
              ),
            ) : (_productProvider.latestOffset == (Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context, listen: false).latestPageSize / 10).ceil())
                ? SizedBox() :
            SizedBox(
              width: 500,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                style : ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                ),
                onPressed: (){
                  _productProvider.moreProduct(context);
                  },
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                  child: Text(getTranslated('see_more', context), style: poppinsRegular.copyWith(fontSize: Dimensions.FONT_SIZE_OVER_LARGE)),
                ),
              ),
            ) : prodProvider.isLoading
                ? Center(child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_SMALL), child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Theme.of(context).primaryColor,)),
            )) : SizedBox.shrink(),
          ) : SizedBox.shrink(),
        ]);
      },
    );
```

Comment: can u be more specific. Like images of  1. what u wanna have  2. what u r getting now

Comment: No problem at the moment.
Popular products are listed to the right.
I want them to be sorted by bottom.

Comment: then reverse the list. like, productsList.reverse()

Comment: Horizontalları vertical olaraq dəyişirəm.
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#5cf02 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 2009 pos 12: 'hasSize'
Yuxarıdakı xətanı alıram.
Araşdırmalarıma görə problem hündürlükdədir. Expanded və SingleChildScrollView var. Sadəcə onu hara əlavə eliyəcəyimi bilmirəm

Comment: I don't want it to be in descending order. I just want to change the design.

Comment: then change the direction . scrollDirection: Axis.Vertical

Comment: I checked. It doesn't work

Comment: can u add a img

Comment: https://streamable.com/rxjye1

Comment: Column(children: [Expanded(child: GridView.builder( ....))  [just add Expanded & put ur GridView.builder inside of it]

Comment: Error:RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#13cbd relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 2009 pos 12: 'hasSize'
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
Null check operator used on a null value

Comment: cool then Delete the Expanded & add SizedBox( height: ..., width:...., child: GridView.builder()... ). Remember hegiht & width must be initialized

Comment: unfortunately the same errors

Comment: return productType == ProductType.POPULAR_PRODUCT
            ? SizedBox( height: 250, width 300, ). Add width here

Comment: unfortunately the same errors

Comment: can u tell where is error indicating ?

Comment: Error:RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#13cbd relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 2009 pos 12: 'hasSize' RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded. Null check operator used on a null value

Comment: just to do 1 thing put every ListView.builder & GridViewBuilder inside of SizedBox each & define height & width both must..

Comment: Can you edit and post the code?

Answer (score 0):

Edited Code

```dart
final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Consumer<ProductProvider>(
      builder: (context, prodProvider, child) {
        List<Product> productList = [];
        if (productType == ProductType.LATEST_PRODUCT) {
          productList = prodProvider.latestProductList;
        } else if (productType == ProductType.POPULAR_PRODUCT) {
          productList = prodProvider.popularProductList;
        }
        if (productList == null) {
          return SizedBox(
            height: 250,
            width: size.width,
            child: productType == ProductType.POPULAR_PRODUCT
                ? ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: 10,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
                      );
                    },
                  )
                : GridView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    gridDelegate: ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context)
                        ? const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                            maxCrossAxisExtent: 195, mainAxisExtent: 250)
                        : SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisSpacing: 5,
                            mainAxisSpacing: 5,
                            childAspectRatio: 4,
                            crossAxisCount: ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context)
                                ? 3
                                : ResponsiveHelper.isTab(context)
                                    ? 2
                                    : 1,
                          ),
                    itemCount: 12,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context)
                          ? ProductWidgetWebShimmer()
                          : ProductShimmer(isEnabled: productList == null);
                    },
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_SMALL),
                  ),
          );
        }
        if (productList.isEmpty) {
          return const SizedBox();
        }

        return productType == ProductType.POPULAR_PRODUCT
            ? SizedBox(
                height: 250,
                width: size.width,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: productList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
                      width: 195,
                      child: ProductWidgetWeb(
                          product: productList[index], fromPopularItem: true),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            : SizedBox(
                height: size.height,
                width: size.width,
                child: Column(children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: GridView.builder(
                      gridDelegate: ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context)
                          ? const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                              maxCrossAxisExtent: 195, mainAxisExtent: 250)
                          : SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                              crossAxisSpacing: 5,
                              mainAxisSpacing: 5,
                              childAspectRatio: 3.5,
                              crossAxisCount:
                                  ResponsiveHelper.isTab(context) ? 2 : 1,
                            ),
                      itemCount: productList.length,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_EXTRA_SMALL),
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context)
                            ? Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                child: ProductWidgetWeb(
                                    product: productList[index]),
                              )
                            : ProductWidget(product: productList[index]);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 30),
                  productList != null
                      ? Padding(
                          padding: ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context)
                              ? const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, bottom: 70)
                              : const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          child: ResponsiveHelper.isDesktop(context)
                              ? prodProvider.isLoading
                                  ? Center(
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                                            Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_SMALL),
                                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                            valueColor:
                                                AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                                    Theme.of(context)
                                                        .primaryColor)),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  : (_productProvider.latestOffset ==
                                          (Provider.of<ProductProvider>(context,
                                                          listen: false)
                                                      .latestPageSize /
                                                  10)
                                              .ceil())
                                      ? const SizedBox()
                                      : SizedBox(
                                          width: 500,
                                          child: ElevatedButton(
                                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context)
                                                  .primaryColor,
                                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.circular(
                                                          30)),
                                            ),
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              _productProvider
                                                  .moreProduct(context);
                                            },
                                            child: Padding(
                                              padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                      vertical: 10),
                                              child: Text(
                                                  getTranslated(
                                                      'see_more', context),
                                                  style: poppinsRegular.copyWith(
                                                      fontSize: Dimensions
                                                          .FONT_SIZE_OVER_LARGE)),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        )
                              : prodProvider.isLoading
                                  ? Center(
                                      child: Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                                          Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_SMALL),
                                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                          valueColor:
                                              AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                        Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                      )),
                                    ))
                                  : const SizedBox.shrink(),
                        )
                      : const SizedBox.shrink(),
                ]),
              );
      },
    );
```

Comment: unfortunately the same errors

Comment: try doing one thing. replace each of the widget at a time  with Container (hieght:.. width:.., color:....). try to find out which one is causing error?

Comment: A build function returned null. The offending widget is: ProductView Build functions must never return null. To return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill available room, return "Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as possible, return "Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)". See also: https://flutter.dev/ docs/testing/errors

Comment: When I posted the code you provided it gave this error

Comment: do u still stuck ? if so then share ur github file & come to TeamViewer or GoogleMeet

Comment: Give me your email and I'll send you a link. Thanks